# Optimal way to manage data cleaning data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Prior to subsequent analysis I clean my data using the pandas library. Normally I make lots of small functions which do specific tasks:

```
def clean_str_columns(df, column):
    # do something to the dataframe
    df[column] = df[column].str.strip()
    # do more things
    return df
```

and then call them :

```
df = clean_str_columns(df, 'column_name')
```

If I am correct, when I pass the `df` to the function it makes a local reference to the `df` object which means this should give equivalent results:

```
def clean_str_columns(df, column):
    # do something to the dataframe
    df[column] = df[column].str.strip()
    # do more things
```

then:

```
clean_str_columns(df, 'column_name')
```

and the df object will be edited so my global reference will point to the edited object.

What is the 'best style' when editing such dfs in place?

I am primarily concerned with this because when I am working with lots of functions and cleaning a large `df` I often get a `MemoryError`. I keep track of my variables with the %who IPython magic and there are no stray ones and regularly run the Python garbage collector. My `df` is getting smaller (dropping rows and columns) yet I still get this error. So I am concerned that this issue is related to me re-assigning the global reference to the `df` multiple times?

Comment: One issue _may_ be that one of the internal steps in one of your cleaning functions temporarily makes the df bigger behind-the-scenes, before making the output smaller

Comment: I'm pretty convinced its not so transient. For example, I will have finished all functions, ran some multiple times as I test things, and then try to make a new pd.Series object: MemoryError. If I restart the kernel, then run all the functions (with no repeats) again it will allow me to make the series.  Something somewhere is staying in memory and I was wondering if it was related to my referencing? Maybe its an argument for not using an interactive shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using `pd.DataFrame.pipe` if your `dataframe` gets changed by a set of functions, it takes as argument the function to apply, you could also see the local variable on your session using `dir()`, if your dataframe is not deleted by the garbage collector you would find it there

Comment: That's  great, I wasn't aware of the `.pipe` method, that will help tidy things up. Maybe it will fix my memory issues. I could get some quite long pipes, but at least it is easy to read.
 
Thanks about the comment about `dir()` I usually use the `%who` magic, but it looks like dir() has some more coverage.

Comment: I'm not sure if thar would solve the memory problem, let me know if it does so ^^.

Comment: It doesn't look like the .pipe method edits things in place. So lots of `df = df.pipe(function)`... Does this delete the original df object?

Comment: no it doesn't delete it, but the intermediate ones get normally deleted along the way unless they are referenced somewhere else .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? What are the memory implications for : `df = pd.DataFrame(…)` and then `df = df.pipe(function)`?

Comment: I just checked the source code of pipe, it turns out it's just equivalent to `df = function(df)`. I guess your memory problem is due to some reference of your local variables inside your functions preventing the garbage collector from deleting it.

Comment: But don't these references disappear when the function has finished executing? It's also strange that the example shown in the documentation doesn't change anything, regardless of what the function returns?